# How to trigger a prompt redraw when the terminal window size changes?

Tags: bash, shell, readline, iterm2

So I created a trap to check if my terminal (both kitty and iTerm) are registering the change:

```
trap ‘echo $COLUMNS’ WINCH
```

And they are. But none of them attempt to redraw my prompt, neither from re issuing the $PROMPT_COMMAND or by printing $PS1. So now I’ve got two options as far as I can tell.

Use the trap to either issue a ctrl-c or similar or to somehow use tput to move the cursor around and manually redraw the prompt.

So how can I best redraw the prompt when a window resize happens?

Comment: Not a big deal. Live with it.

Comment: It’s a huge deal, when you consider all the other events that could trigger a prompt redraw. Time change, git changes done in a different shell.